# Python - How to match and replace words from a given string?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a array list with large collection, and i have one input string. Large collecion if found in the input string, it will replace by given option.

I tried following but its returning wrong:

```
#!/bin/python
arr=['www.', 'http://', '.com', 'many many many....']
def str_replace(arr, replaceby, original):
  temp = ''
  for n,i in enumerate(arr):
    temp = original.replace(i, replaceby)
  return temp

main ='www.google.com'
main1='www.a.b.c.company.google.co.uk.com'
print str_replace(arr,'',main);
```

Output:

```
www.google
```

Expected:

```
google
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't even need `temp` (assuming the above code is the whole function):

```
def str_replace(search, replace, subject):
    for s in search:
        subject = subject.replace(s, replace)
    return subject
```

Another (probably more efficient) option is to use regular expressions:

```
import re

def str_replace(search, replace, subject):
    search = '|'.join(map(re.escape, search))
    return re.sub(search, replace, subject)
```

Do note that these functions may produce different results if `replace` contains substrings from `search`.

Comment: Regex is probably *less* efficient for simple string replacement.

Comment: @Junuxx: see timings in [my recent question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10931150/phps-strtr-for-python). Regex clearly wins over cycling replacements provided the subject is long enough.

Answer (score 3):

You are deriving `temp` from the original every time, so only the last element of `arr` will be replaced in the `temp` that is returned. Try this instead:

```
def str_replace(arr, replaceby, original):
  temp = original
  for n,i in enumerate(arr):
    temp = temp.replace(i, replaceby)
  return temp
```

Comment: I can't understand what `enumerate` is supposed to be doing here.

Comment: @Daniel: Good point, nothing really. But maybe OP left out irrelevant parts of the code, where `n` is used?

Answer (score 1):

```
temp = original.replace(i, replaceby)
```

It should be

```
temp = temp.replace(i, replaceby)
```

You're throwing away the previous substitutions.

Answer (score 1):

Simple way :)

```
arr=['www.', 'http://', '.com', 'many many many....']
main ='http://www.google.com'
for item in arr:
    main = main.replace(item,'')
print main
```