# php's strtr for python

Tags: python, string

php has the [`strtr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php)  function:

```
strtr('aa-bb-cc', array('aa' => 'bbz', 'bb' => 'x', 'cc' => 'y'));
# bbz-x-y
```

It replaces dictionary keys in a string with corresponding values and (important) doesn't replace already replaced strings. A naive attempt to write the same in python:

```
def strtr(strng, replace):
    for s, r in replace.items():
        strng = strng.replace(s, r)
    return strng

strtr('aa-bb-cc', {'aa': 'bbz', 'bb': 'x', 'cc': 'y'})
```

returns `xz-x-y` which is not we want (`bb` got replaced again). How to change the above function so that it behaves like its php counterpart?

(I would prefer an answer without regular expressions, if possible).

Upd: some great answers here. I timed them and found that for short strings Gumbo's version appears to be the fastest, on longer strings the winner  is the `re` solution:

```
# 'aa-bb-cc'
0.0258 strtr_thg
0.0274 strtr_gumbo
0.0447 strtr_kojiro
0.0701 strtr_aix

# 'aa-bb-cc'*10
0.1474 strtr_aix
0.2261 strtr_thg
0.2366 strtr_gumbo
0.3226 strtr_kojiro
```

My own version (which is slightly optimized Gumbo's):

```
def strtr(strng, replace):
    buf, i = [], 0
    while i < len(strng):
        for s, r in replace.items():
            if strng[i:len(s)+i] == s:
                buf.append(r)
                i += len(s)
                break
        else:
            buf.append(strng[i])
            i += 1
    return ''.join(buf)
```

Complete codes and timings: https://gist.github.com/2889181

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a naive algorithm:

Use an index to walk the original string character by character and check for each index whether one of the search strings is equal to the string from the current index on. If a match is found, push the replacement in a buffer and proceed the index by the length of the matched string. If no match is found, proceed the index by one. At the end, concatenate the strings in the buffer to a single string.

```
def strtr(strng, replace):
    buffer = []
    i, n = 0, len(strng)
    while i < n:
        match = False
        for s, r in replace.items():
            if strng[i:len(s)+i] == s:
                buffer.append(r)
                i = i + len(s)
                match = True
                break
        if not match:
            buffer.append(strng[i])
            i = i + 1
    return ''.join(buffer)
```

Comment: We're both missing this (from the strtr doc): The longest keys will be tried first.

Answer (score 9):

The following uses regular expressions to do it:

```
import re

def strtr(s, repl):
  pattern = '|'.join(map(re.escape, sorted(repl, key=len, reverse=True)))
  return re.sub(pattern, lambda m: repl[m.group()], s)

print(strtr('aa-bb-cc', {'aa': 'bbz', 'bb': 'x', 'cc': 'y'}))
```

Like the PHP's version, this gives preference to longer matches.

Comment: No, it doesn't give preference to longer matches, it depends on the arbitrary order of dictionary keys: `strtr('xxa-bb-cc', { 'xx': 'bbz', 'xxa': 'bby'})` -> `'bbza-bb-cc'`. Using `sorted(repl.keys(), key=len, reverse=True)` in place of `repl.keys()` should fix that.

Comment: @Duncan: How surprising, thanks for pointing out (I always thought Python's `re` gave the longest match, but clearly it doesn't.)

Comment: Repetitions `x*`, `x+`, `x?` and `x{m,n}` are all greedy, so they'll repeat `x` as much as they're allowed and able, `x*?`, `x+?`, `x??`, `x{m,n}?` are all non-greedy so they match as short as possible. `x|y` is also non-greedy in the sense that if `x` matches the engine won't even consider `y`. That's what happened here: the alternation is tested strictly left to right and stops as soon as it finds a match.

Comment: @Duncan: That makes sense, thanks for clarifying (I knew about the greedy and non-greedy repetitions, but didn't know about the `|` operator).

Comment: Thanks, this solution appears to be the fastest on longer subject strings (see the update).

Comment: Thanks from Rust! This solution is readily portable to other languages, is usually highly efficient given a properly-working DFA regex engine, and can easily be further improved on heavy substitutions by caching the compiled regex. And here I was thinking I might need to make a trie manually!

Answer (score 5):

```
def strtr(strng, replace):
    if replace and strng:
        s, r = replace.popitem()
        return r.join(strtr(subs, dict(replace)) for subs in strng.split(s))
    return strng

j=strtr('aa-bb-cc', {'aa': 'bbz', 'bb': 'x', 'cc': 'y'})
assert j=='bbz-x-y', j
```

Comment: Looks cool, but making `1+2+...+len(repl)` recursive calls... I don't know.

Comment: Hey, you asked for a non-regex version that behaves like php's, you didn't ask for fast. ;) (Besides, I suspect copying the dict is worse than the recursive calls.)

Comment: @kojiro: fair enough. You definitely win the beauty prize in this thread. Too bad I can't accept multiple answers...

Comment: BTW, is there any reason why you used `**` instead of just `dict(replace)`?

Comment: No good reason. The bad reason is that I didn't take time to check that dict(adict) would make a copy, instead of just returning the same dict. – updated answer code.

Answer (score 4):

[`str.translate`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) is the equivalent, but can only map to single characters.

Answer (score 0):

The answers on this thread are so out-dated. Here we go...

#### Option #1: Use the str.format() function to handle this:

```
"Hello there {first_name} {last_name}".format(first_name="Bob", last_name="Roy")
```

#### Option #2: Use the Template class

```
from string import Template
t = Template('Hello there $first_name $last_name')
t.substitute(first_name="Bob", last_name="Roy")
```

Reference: 
[Python String Formatting Best Practices](https://realpython.com/python-string-formatting/)

Comment: Both require specifically-formatted template strings, which is not a possibility for many of strtr's use cases. One I am pretty familiar with is MediaWiki's LanguageConverter.