# Search and replace numbers with words in file

Tags: python, regex, file, search, replace

I have a file that contains numbers and letters and I want to replace all the numbers to words (for example, 8 is converted to eight). Well I just don't get a way to check if there is numbers on my file. What is the best effective way to do this?

Comment: you can create your dictionary `{1: "one", 2: "two"...}` and use the [following answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14156473/can-you-write-a-str-replace-using-dictionary-values-in-python)

Comment: "best effective way" depends on a lot of things.

Answer (score 11):

The following should work, it reads an input file, uses a regex to find all of the numbers,  and the [num2words](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/num2words) library to replace each with text:

```
import re
import num2words


with open('input.txt') as f_input:
    text = f_input.read()

text = re.sub(r"(\d+)", lambda x: num2words.num2words(int(x.group(0))), text)

with open('output.txt', 'w') as f_output:
    f_output.write(text)
```

The `num2words` library can be installed using:

```
pip install num2words
```

So if your input text file contained:

```
Today 1000 people wrote 500 words to make 321 questions.
```

The output would be:

```
Today one thousand people wrote five hundred words to make three hundred and twenty-one questions.
```

Answer (score 2):

This is just to find the numbers present in the file, if you dont know how to replace,use dictionary.

```
import re
text = open('text_numbers.txt')

for line in text:
    line = line.strip()
    y = re.findall('([0-9]+)',line)
```

Answer (score 1):

This question was also answered here : [replacing text in a file with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13089234/replacing-text-in-a-file-with-python)

If you want to discuss the memory user and other topics, this question should do the trick : [Search for string in txt file Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4940032/search-for-string-in-txt-file-python)

Some people explained the different usage of different function to read a text from a file, but in your case, it look like it's not a huge file so the first link should give you the answer.

Just remember, when you parse a txt file, even "8" is a String.

Answer (score 1):

You find the numbers using regex and then you can convert the number to words with using [num2words](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/num2words) package. And simply replace them.

```
In [1]: from num2words import num2words
In [2]: num2words(54)
Out[2]: u'fifty-four'
In [3]: num2words(8)
Out[3]: u'eight'
```