# I already got the answer but just curious why this method won't this work ? The output looks as if only the last if statement is valid

Tags: python

> Write a program that takes a simple password and makes it stronger by replacing characters using the key below, and by appending "q*s" to the end of the input string.
>
> - `i` becomes `!`
> - `a` becomes `@`
> - `m` becomes `M`
> - `B` becomes `8`
> - `o` becomes `.`

```
word = input()

password = ''

if 'a' in x:
    password = word.replace('a', '@')
if 'i' in x:
    password = word.replace('i', '!')
if 'm' in x:
    password = word.replace('m', 'M')
if 'B' in x:
    password = word.replace('B', '8')
if 'o' in x:
    password = word.replace('o', '.')
        
print(password)
```

Comment: I don't see why this was edited to have the `if` statements in a loop. That would only make sense if the conditions were of the form `x == 'a'`. I assume `x` has the same value as `word` in which case `'a' in x` is `True` if the string `x` contains the `'a'` character.

Comment: You don't need the loop or the `if` statements. You just need to chain calls to `replace.

Comment: Or `str.translate` - [https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate).

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning each replacement of `word` to `password` without updating `word`. So, it's stays the same.

Let's say the password is "ai":

First, it takes "a" and because "a" is in "a", it does

```
password = "@i"  # "ai".replace('a', '@')
```

Then, it takes "i" and because "i" is in "i", it does

```
password =  "a!" # "ai".replace('i', '!')
```

And you keep only the last assignement!

As commented by @chepner, you don't need to use an if statement, you can just call replace, and replacement are going to occur only if the character is present. Also, is not necessary to make a new assignment every time:

```
password = word.replace('a', '@')\
               .replace('i', '!')\
               .replace('m', 'M')\
               .replace('B', '8')\
               .replace('o', '.')
```

I like to write it like that, in multiple lines, so it's easy to keep track of the replacements.

Or maybe you want to state the replacements in a dictionary, so [you can do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14156473/can-you-write-a-str-replace-using-dictionary-values-in-python):

```
replacements = {'a': '@', 'i': '!', 'm': 'M', 'B': '8', 'o': '.'}
password = word

for character in replacements.keys():
    password = password.replace(character, replacements[character])
```

Comment: So how do I update word at the same time?

Comment: Ok, I understood you had an answer and just wanted to understand the source of the problem. I'll update the answer now.

Answer (score 0):

Just chain the replace statements together, e.g.:

```
'iBOoAF912Iib9'.replace('i','!').replace('a','@').replace('m','M').replace('B','8').replace('o','.')
```