# Covert categorical user input into numerical

Tags: python

so I'm trying to change the data that the user enters through the form into a string.

this is the code for the combobox

```
Status_bangunan_cb = Combobox(window, textvariable = STATUS_BANGUNAN,values=['1. Milik Sendiri','2. Kontrak/Sewa','3. Bebas Sewa','4. Dinas','5. Lainnya'],
                             font=14,state='r',width=33).place(x=320,y=110)
```

and here is the output

```
1. Milik Sendiri
```

but the output i want is 1, so the previous user input is converted to a number.

I have tried using the following code

```
Status_bangunan.replace({'1. Milik Sendiri':1,'2. Kontrak/Sewa':2,'3. Bebas Sewa':3,'4. Dinas':4,'5. Lainnya':5}, inplace=True)
```

but it doesn't work, and here is the error

```
TypeError: str.replace() takes no keyword arguments
```

then I also tried the following code

```
SB = Status_bangunan.replace('1. Milik Sendiri','1')
```

the result

```
1
```

the code works but only for 1 part, what I want is for all of them to be automatically converted not just 1. but str.replace() function only for 2 arguments.

the result that I expect is that when the user inputs through the form (categorical) the results obtained will be automatically converted to numbers

I'm still confused about this, please help.
for the form I use python gui

i have tried this code

```
Dict1 = {"1. Milik Sendiri":"1", "2. Kontrak/Sewa":"2","3. Bebas Sewa":"3","4. Dinas":"4","5. Lainnya":"5"} 
    for key in Dict1.keys():
        SB = Status_bangunan.replace(key, Dict1[key])
```

but the result

```
1. Milik Sendiri
```

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14156473/can-you-write-a-str-replace-using-dictionary-values-in-python/) post is related to and answers your question. It describes a way of using the replace-function.

Comment: I have tried it but still not getting results

Comment: Try `int(status.split('. ')[0])`

Comment: The `replace` method can only replace strings with strings, it's not what you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `replace` method can only replace strings by strings: `'alpha beta gamma'.replace('bet','delt') == 'alpha delta gamma'` Note it's used to replace *part* of a string, you wouldn't use it if you want to change the entire string.

Also, strings are immutable, so a `in-place` option makes no sense.

You can either do this:

```
{
    '1. Milik Sendiri': 1,
    '2. Kontrak/Sewa': 2,
    '3. Bebas Sewa': 3,
    '4. Dinas': 4,
    '5. Lainnya': 5
}[Status_bangunan]
```

This is basically just your second idea but no replace method. There is no need for it.

Another option is to parse the text. This extracts thee part beefore the `.`  then parses it as a integer:

```
# Parse as integer
int(
   Status_bangunan
       # Split into a list of strings, seperated by a `. `
       .split('. ')
          # Take the first part, which will thus be the part before the .
          [0])
```

Comment: so i tried the code like this
Dict1 = {
                '1. Milik Sendiri': 1,
                '2. Kontrak/Sewa': 2,
                '3. Bebas Sewa': 3,
                '4. Dinas': 4,
                '5. Lainnya': 5
            }[Status_bangunan]
    int(Status_bangunan.split('. ')[0])
    for key in Dict1.keys():
        int(Status_bangunan.split('. ')[0])
        SB = Status_bangunan.replace(key, Dict1[key])

this the error message 
'int' object has no attribute 'keys'

sorry if i miss understanding your help

Comment: No, as I clearly state you don't want to use `replace` since it always returns a string, not a int.

Comment: so when i delete the replace function, theres no error but the output didnt change into numeric

Comment: Just use the code I posted. It works. All your extra things don't

Comment: I've done it but the output is still 1. Milik Sendiri, not numeric. I've changed the code exactly as posted

Comment: Make sure to use the return value of these expressions. They create new values, don't modify anything.