# How can I use REGEX to replace words in a string with their corresponding abbreviations from a separate array?

Tags: arrays, regex, replace

I have 2 string arrays, one is a list of words and the other a list of abbreviations for those words. Is there a way using REGEX that I can replace any of the words from list one that are found in the string, with the appropriate abbreviation from list two?

```
Const DirectionalNames As String = "(North|East|South|West|Northeast|Southeast|Northwest|Southwest)"
Const DirectionalStandards As String = "(N|E|S|W|NE|SE|NW|SW)"

MySample as string = "Go North, then take the Southeast highway for 5 miles."
```

Want to change it to: "Go N, then take the SE highway for 5 miles."

**Thanks in Advance.**

Tried various forms of replace using REGEX but couldn't find anything that worked.

Comment: In what language? In most languages you can use a function as the replacement, and it can look up the match in a mapping data structure.

Comment: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14156473/can-you-write-a-str-replace-using-dictionary-values-in-python) shows how to do it in Python. It will be similar in JavaScript and PHP.

Comment: If you don't mind case, you could use a (language agnostic) regexp replace [llike **this demo**](https://regex101.com/r/aCNpwi/2).