# Replacing substrings given a dictionary of strings-to-be-replaced as keys and replacements as values. Python

Tags: python, string, dictionary, replace

I have a dictionary with the **strings to be replaced** as `keys` and its **replacement** as values. Other than looking through the strings token by token, is there a better/faster way of doing the replacement?

I've been doing it as such:

```
segmenter = {'foobar':'foo bar', 'withoutspace':'without space', 'barbar': 'bar bar'}

sentence = "this is a foobar in a barbar withoutspace"

for i in sentence.split():
  if i in segmenter:
    sentence.replace(i, segmenter[i])
```

Comment: I've asked the [same question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10931150/989121) a while ago. Some nice answers there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

String are immutable in python. So, `str.replace` returns a new string instead of modifying the original string. You can use `str.join()` and list comprehension here:

```
>>> segmenter = {'foobar':'foo bar', 'withoutspace':'without space', 'barbar': 'bar bar'}
>>> sentence = "this is a foobar in a barbar withoutspace"

>>> " ".join( [ segmenter.get(word,word) for word in sentence.split()] )
'this is a foo bar in a bar bar without space'
```

Another problem with `str.replace` is that it'll also replace  words like `"abarbarb"` with

`"abar barb"`.

Answer (score 4):

`re.sub` can call a function that returns the substitution

```
segmenter = {'foobar':'foo bar', 'withoutspace':'without space', 'barbar': 'bar bar'}
sentence = "this is a foobar in a barbar withoutspace"

import re

def fn(match):
    return segmenter[match.group()]

print re.sub('|'.join(re.escape(k) for k in segmenter), fn, sentence)
```

Comment: +1 This is more idiomatic and controllable than the split/get/join approach.  One nit:  when building a combined regex like this, be sure to do a descending sort by key length so that longer keys like "without" don't masked by shorter keys like "with".  Alternatively, use a "\b" to locate the word boundaries and prevent aliasing between keys.