# replace substrings based on index range with dictionary values from a string

Tags: python, arrays, string, python-3.x

I have the following string/sentence ( not grammatically correct)

```
s = "The user should be able to audit log to view the audit log entries."
```

And I have a dictionary with similar keys:

```
d = {'audit' : 'class1',
    'audit log' : 'class2',
    'audit log entries' : 'class3'}
```

I'm able to get the index ranges of substrings which will match the keys in dictionary and I need to replace the keys matched with their values.

```
   final_ranges = [(49, 66), (27, 36)] #list length may vary
```

I want to iterate over the index ranges and replace the substrings.

I tried the following code:

```
for i in final_ranges:
    for k,v in d.items():
        if s[i[0]:i[1]] == k:
            print(s[0:i[0]] + v + s[i[1]:])
```

which will output:

```
The user should be able to audit log to view the class3.
The user should be able to class2 to view the audit log entries.
```

But I want the substring replacements to occur in one sentence itself.

```
The user should be able to class2 to view the class3.
```

I went through this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16516623/replacing-substrings-given-a-dictionary-of-strings-to-be-replaced-as-keys-and-re) . But it is not based on index ranges.

Comment: Why do you want to use index ranges? It would simpler just to .replace()

Comment: @mfitzp The index ranges are output of another code and I should be replacing those keys only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't actually update `s` ever. So, your changes don't accrue. Try this:

```
for i in final_ranges:
    key = s[i[0]:i[1]]
    if (key in d):
        s = s[:i[0]] + d[key] + s[i[1]:]
        print(s)
```

Although, as has been stated in the comments, you should probably use replace:

```
for k, v in d.items():
    s = s.replace(k, v)
    print(s)
```

You can even do this as a list comprehension if you're willing to drop the `print` statement:

```
from functools import reduce
s = reduce(lambda string, kv: string.replace(kv[0], kv[1]), d.items(), s)
```

Comment: Only the index range keys need to be changed. Otherwise, as the keys are similar, it would replace with class1 as value and not specifically class2 & class3 as values